# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException,Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper

Tags: java, classloader, jackson-databind

I get the following error when trying to run a java program that uses jackson's ObjectMapper class:

> ```
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at cn.env.web.pagebg.device.Receiver.receive(Receiver.java:129)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> at cn.env.filter.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:26)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2527)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2516)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> ```

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper
at com.ndww.codec.Station.<init>(Station.java:13)
at com.ndww.station.AirStation.<init>(AirStation.java:13)
at com.ndww.codec.ProtocolAdapter.decode(ProtocolAdapter.java:25)
... 49 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 52 more
```

here's the dependencies section of my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

here's the code section that throws errors:

```
    File file = new File("C:/Java/apache-tomcat-8.0.50/webapps/envm/WEB-INF/lib/CODEC-5DTecheSDK-06.jar");
    URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
    ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url});
    Class<?> cls = loader.loadClass("com.ndww.codec.ProtocolAdapter");
    Method method = cls.getMethod("decode",String.class);
    Object o = method.invoke(null,sensorData);
```

junit test is fine,but running in tomcat is wrong.
I am a bit confused. Could someone please tell me why is that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven, you dont have to manually classload de jar. You are able to use all the jars importing them in your java class:

For example, if you add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

in you java file, you have to import:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerationException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


And them use the mapper: 
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            time_start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Result obj = mapper.readValue(new File("path_to_file"), Result.class);      

        } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If you use STS or eclipse, try to make a Maven project and when you are in classes you have to can use organize imports to auto import the packages.

One more thing, for exporting the project just execute mvn package and make sure you define in your pom.xml "war packaging" for making the war and deploy it on tomcat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Please look at the code section again,I do not have manually loaded jackson-xxx.jar

Comment: sorry, It´s true. Can you see the war package includes the libraries of jackson? It looks like tomcat can´t see that jars in WEB-INF/lib

Comment: Thank you so much,your answer gave me a clue to solve the problem,my English is not very good and cannot describe my solution in detail.This problem has troubled me for days,thanks anyway!